# How to sort name by alphabetically in drupal views?

Tags: views

I have created view in this drupal 7 views,there are Two pages are created in that view.

> page 1:Images page
>
> page 2:List view page

here i have tried in List view page by using sort criteria of Name field(ASC or DESC). but Names are sorted in List view page correctly.

- When i am click Name field for sorting in second page(List view) automatically that fields are sorted in first page(Images) page also.
- That sorting is not working in views.
- First page taking only default sorting order.

Here is screen shorts
[image]
[image]

Here sorting values are not stored database permanently.If i click refresh button views default sorting behavior is added to that pages.

Is it possible to sort the two view pages permanently?

Answer (score 1):

we have a module called [Views Glossary](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary) once u install the module we have to enable in stucture->views->glossary view like archive for dats and months

[image]